# I get an error when I try to add my .accdb file as a new connection

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2013

This is the error I get when I try to add my .accdb file as a new connection in Visual Studio 2013:

[image: Y6tEYn1.png]

The message in English is "Unrecognized Database Format".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well you know I created a few tables in MS-Acces and filled them. Saved it ( as an accdb file). In Visual studio's server explorer I tried to add a new connection resulting in the error ^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a version compatibility issue. You need to use an older provider (`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`) in order to access the older Access database format.

Click advanced in the first dialog:

[image]

and change the provider to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

[image]

If that isn't available you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I saw it when I googled this before I asked it here. But my friend said he had done it without installing something extra.